# Update linq objects on web service

Tags: c#, linq, web-services

I am working on a project that uses a web service. The web service uses linq-to-entities to talk to a mysql database. Currently I am returning linq entities to a windows client, the entities are updated on the client, changing properties such as description, brand, release date etc. I am now trying to return these updated objects to the web service and update them in the database using the attach method, but it is not working. What is the simplest way to update these objects in the database?

Current Code:

Web Service:

```
public class MobilePartService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    MobilePartsEntities _DataContext = new MobilePartsEntities();

    [WebMethod]
    public List<Mobile> GetMobiles()
    {
        return _DataContext.Mobiles.ToList();
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public void UpdateMobile(Mobile prMobile)
    {
        _DataContext.Attach(prMobile);
        _DataContext.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

Client Update Code:

```
_Mobile.Brand = txtBrand.Text;
_Mobile.Decription = txtDescription.Text;
_Mobile.ModelNumber = txtModelNumber.Text;
_Mobile.ReleaseDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtReleaseDate.Text);    
clsGlobal.Service.UpdateMobile(_Mobile);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something else between the `Attach` and the `SaveChanges` calls. [See this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896248.aspx), which has this example:

```
    context.SalesOrderDetails.Attach(updatedItem);
    // Check if the ID is 0, if it is the item is new. 
    // In this case we need to chage the state to Added.
    if (updatedItem.SalesOrderDetailID == 0)
    {
        // Because the ID is generated by the database we do not need to
        // set updatedItem.SalesOrderDetailID.
        context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(updatedItem, System.Data.EntityState.Added);
    }
    else
    {
        // If the SalesOrderDetailID is not 0, then the item is not new
        // and needs to be updated. Because we already added the 
        // updated object to the context we need to apply the original values.
        // If we attached originalItem to the context 
        // we would need to apply the current values:
        // context.ApplyCurrentValues("SalesOrderDetails", updatedItem);
        // Applying current or original values, changes the state 
        // of the attached object to Modified.
        context.ApplyOriginalValues("SalesOrderDetails", originalItem);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
```